# Android connection to server not being recognized or throwing an error. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, android, apache, networking

I'm attempting to push JSON data to a server via an android application and can't isolate the problem. The server doesn't receive the connection at all, but the client side doesn't indicate any problems.

```
public void getServerData() throws JSONException, ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    ResponseHandler <String> resonseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost("HTTP://URL_GOES_HERE/FOLDER");
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    //Log.v("JSON being sent", json.toString());
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("jsonString", json.toString()));
    postMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    String response = httpClient.execute(postMethod,resonseHandler);

    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
    Log.v("beginresponse","beginresponse");
    Log.v("server response", jsonResponse.toString());
    Log.v("endresponse","endresponse");
    //Log.v("msg to server", json.toString());
```

}

Here's some sample log output:

```
10-20 11:31:09.195: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=1) - NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault(25802): (thUse=1) NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault()
10-20 11:31:09.205: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=1) - NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault(25802): (thUse=1)    cached value : gbaSupportIsPossible=null
10-20 11:31:09.205: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=1) - NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault(25802): (thUse=1)    The current context is NOT a context of GBA service.
10-20 11:31:09.215: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=1) - GbaSupportPermissionRequestCheckerImpl(25802): (thUse=1) isCurrentProcessRequestedGba()#finished   result=false
10-20 11:31:09.215: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=1) - GbaSupportPermissionRequestCheckerImpl(25802): (thUse=1) isCurrentProcessAllowedToUseGba()#started   result=false
10-20 11:31:09.215: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=1) - NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault(25802): (thUse=1)    The GBA permission wasn't requested for this process.
10-20 11:31:09.215: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=1) - NafHttpAuthStrategyDefault(25802): (thUse=1) It is impossible to support GBA now (many possible reasons: no Android Context, current client is GBA service, etc.), then it will be just usual HTTP.
10-20 11:31:09.215: I/APACHE HTTP (thCr=1) - NafRequestExecutorWrapperRedirectionHandler(25802): (thUse=1)    It isn't GBA flow, redirection responses are not handled.
10-20 11:31:09.226: W/MediaRecorder(25802): mediarecorder went away with unhandled events
10-20 11:31:12.008: D/memalloc(25802): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5ba42000 size:1536000
10-20 11:31:12.008: D/memalloc(25802): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5bcb9000 size:1536000
10-20 11:31:12.008: D/memalloc(25802): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5be30000 size:1536000
10-20 11:31:12.018: D/CLIPBOARD(25802): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
10-20 11:31:18.014: D/memalloc(25802): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5ba42000 size:1536000 offset:0 fd:46
10-20 11:31:18.074: D/memalloc(25802): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5bcb9000 size:1536000 offset:0 fd:53
10-20 11:31:23.439: D/memalloc(25802): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5be30000 size:1536000 offset:0 fd:56
10-20 11:31:23.580: I/mic(25802): 1
10-20 11:31:23.580: I/path(25802): /mnt/sdcard/most-recent-recording.aac
```

Comment: you should take tcpdump and analyze

Comment: there are quite a lot of tutorials to take tcpdump, but if you are using emulator, you could try [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/104278/how-to-use-wireshark-to-capture-filter-and-inspect-packets/)

Comment: [Doing it through the phone requires root access-- I guess I'll install a virtual device.](http://www.kandroid.org/online-pdk/guide/tcpdump.html#installing)

Comment: not necessarily, if you have access to server, you could run tcpdump on server

Comment: My friend and I now believe it's because the android API doesn't allow for server connections in the main thread. I'll follow up when I figure this noise out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the server connections will not work on UI thread, starting from API 11 I guess. So try to put it into async task.